# Need To transfer DataBase Data From datalist from Page To textbox in Another page

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

How Are You Guys ,,

I'm making a website provides artricles and news for the users ,
i have the articles in database and i put it in datalist in StatPage.aspx , then i have made the items in the datalist HyperLinks so The user can click on it and redirect to View.aspx to View it ,
My Problem is:

1-How to get The data From the Database in DataList when i click the Hyperlink and redirect to View.aspx and Put the data in Text Box Or lable or any Thing ??

Here Is My Code :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BackColor="#FF0066" BorderColor="Black"
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" Width="647px">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            AticleTitle: 
            <asp:HyperLink ID="Title" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"<asp:Label ID="AticleTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AticleTitle") %>' /></asp:HyperLink>
            <br />
            ArticleBody:
            <asp:Label ID="ArticleBodyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleBody") %>' />
            <br />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BrainStormsConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [AticleTitle], [ArticleBody] FROM [Articles]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

pass id of article to page 2 like this:

```
 NavigateUrl='<%# "page2.aspx?id="+ Eval("AticleID") %>'
```

and in page 2 use this id.

Comment: Thanks For the Answer samiey .. can you explain more in detail please ??

Comment: in page 2 put one DataList and one SqlDataSource . in SqlDataSource select command set 'where' by id from queryString